# C Program Help: Unexpected Output

Tags: c, arrays, output

School project for Computer Science. I need to make a program where the user declares a size for an array, then fills the array in numerical, nondecreasing order, then declares a value, x. X is then assigned to the appropriate spot so the entire array is in numerical, nondecreasing order. The array is then output.

The code builds properly with no errors, but the output is messed up.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

//Local Declarations
int size;
int ary[100];
int x;
int i;
int j;

//Statements
printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
scanf("%d", &size);

printf("\nEnter digits to fill the array, in numerical order: ");
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &ary[i]);
}
size++;

printf("\nInput x, the value to add to the array: ");
scanf("%d", &x);

while(i=0 <= x && x > ary[i]){
i++;
j = size - 1;
    while(j >= i) {
        ary[j++] = ary[j];
        j--;
    }
}
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
 printf("%d,", ary[i]);
}

return 0;
} //main
```

Example Output:

```
Enter the size of the array: 5

Enter digits to fill the array, in numerical order: 1
2
3
4
5

Input x, the value to add to the array: 6
1,2,3,4,5,1630076519,
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 8.585 s
Press any key to continue.
```

It's always the last value that messes up to that huge number. I cannot for the life of me figure out why. The project is due by midnight EST.

Comment: What is your intent here `i=0 <= x`? Looks like a logic error.

Comment: `ary[j++] = ary[j];` is also non-logical: the line is assigning the same value to itself.

Comment: I need to return i back to 0, but the program crashes if I just make a statement above the while loop of "i = 0;"

Comment: Great, so that means the logic my professor gave me itself is false and probably causing the problem. Uggggg.

Answer (score 0):

For the `while` loop, can you try this instead,

```
i = 0;
while (i < x && x > ary[i]) {
    i++;
    j = size - 1;
    while (j >= i) {
        j++;
        ary[j] = ary[j];   // Equivalent to ary[j++] = ary[j];, yet easier to read
        j--;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but anytime I add a statement returning the value of i back to 0 before this while loop, the program freezes.

Comment: It is probably that `x > ary[i]` part. What exactly is the assignment suppose to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

//Local Declarations
int size;
int ary[100];
int x;
int i;
int j;
int temp1,temp2;

//Statements
printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
scanf("%d", &size);

printf("\nEnter digits to fill the array, in numerical order: ");
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
scanf("%d", &ary[i]);
}


printf("\nInput x, the value to add to the array: ");
scanf("%d", &x);

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
   if(ary[i]>x)
   {
       temp1 = ary[i];
       ary[i] = x;
       break; 
   }
}
if(i==size)
{
    ary[i]= x;
}
else
{

    for(j=i+1;j<size+1;j++)
    {
       if(j==size) //Last element of the new array
       {
           ary[j] = temp1;
           break;
       }

       temp2 = ary[j];
       ary[j] =temp1;
       temp1 = temp2;


    } 
 }

for(i = 0; i < size+1; i++) {
 printf("%d,", ary[i]);
}

return 0;
} //main
```